# How to echo out bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i wanna echo a bootstrap modal when the user want to submit but they are not full fill the blank yet.
i wanna my modal show that, Please fill all the blank!
i did try this

```
 if ($firstname == "" || $lastname == "" || $username == "" || $pass == "" || $email == "" || $phone == "" || $level =="") {
echo "<script> $('#myModal').modal('show');
           </script>";
```

And this is my data modal (i can not upload this code on this web so i have to post the picture.)

[image]

My code here:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Please fill in the blank!

But when i click on the button it show nothing, Can you help me?

Comment: it would help if you created a mock-up of what you want to do on jsfiddle. Create a simple HTML page, with that dialog (presuming that PHP wants to show it).
We do not have your code, we have no idea what it does and how it is behaving.

Comment: Bad excuse for not putting real code and using an image. You could have copied the code straight from your IDE

Comment: *"i can not upload this code on this web so i have to post the picture"* - doubtful.

Comment: Dear people, i mean i want to add the code of the modal but it seems like can not realize that is the code, i did edit my post and you can see, what will happen when i upload my code.

Comment: Please check console of browser.
So you will know that whether any error in JS or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're just rendering out a jQuery statement blindly in a script tag.  This will be immediately executed by the browser as soon as it's rendered - so more than likely the jQuery library isn't loaded and the $ symbol is unbound which should be blowing up your console.

In general, the pattern of `echo "some mark-up";` is bad.  For any multi-line statement I'd much prefer to see

```
<?php if(some_condition){ ?> 
   just write your mark-up here.
<?php } ?>
```

Try wrapping it in a `$(document).ready(function() { stuff that depends on stuff });` so you at least know jQuery is loaded before it runs.

eg.

```
<?php if ($firstname == "" || $lastname == "" || $username == "" || $pass == "" || $email == "" || $phone == "" || $level =="") { ?>
 <script> 
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
   });
 </script>
<?php } ?>
```